# Hourly deal extension Magento 1.5

Tags: looking-for-a-script, magento

I want to implement hourly basis product deal on my website using Magento 1.5,
administrator has to handle on deal date, time and time duration for that particular product deal.

Can you please suggest me if its there any extension available
or kindly suggest the best solution/idea?

Comment: I think this question is more appropriate for [Magento support forum](http://collaborate.magento.com/magento). ([StackOverflow FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq))

Comment: I posted the same Question on magento support form... They wer not replied..can u please give us a best solution for this

Comment: I understand your reason, but this question is off topic here, IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a thread on the forums that advertises for a daily deal plugin.

> http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/204524/

Since Magento is written in PHP, I can't imagine it would be too hard for you to adjust the timing to hours instead of days.

Answer (score 1):

There just have [Daily deal](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/14112/) and [Group deal] extensions. However, with Daily Deal module, you could run a deal in some certain hours in a day. You could check this module more through the [demo](http://www.magestore.com/magento-daily-deal-extension.html).

Comment: It seems that your are still promoting your website on SE too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,I'll provide you the extension hourly deal extension for Magento ie.[Daily / Multiple Deals Advanced Extension for Magento](https://magento.ocodewire.com/extensions/bw-daily-deals-pro.html). In this extension, admin can set hourly time of the individual products.